# Tile Painting in AP

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, number-theory

Nikita has a row of white tiles indexed from **1** to **N** . She's painting them green!

Find the number of ways Nikita can paint certain tiles in green so that the indices of the green tiles form an **Arithmetic Progression**. As this value can be quite large, your answer must be modulo **1000000007**.

Note: Nikita must paint at least tile.

**N** can be large upto **10000000000**.

My Approach:

For each tiles find the sum of integer partition of the remaining tiles to the right of it.

For e.g.,

**N** = 5

For Tile **1**, **4/1 + 4/2 + 4/3 + 4/4 = 8**

For Tile **2**, **3/1 + 3/2 + 3/3 = 5**

For Tile **3**, **2/1 + 2/2 = 3**

For Tile **4**, **1/1 = 1**

And also, all tiles individually contributes to the answer.

Answer = 5+8+5+3+1 = **22**.

Is my approach right? if so, how to formulate/optimize this or any other approach?

Comment: Are {3,4} or {1,3} valid APs for N=5?

Comment: Yes, there is no restrictions on the size of AP

Comment: @MetaD Feel free for any queries.